# How to Save file in Solution explorer(Asp.net)

Tags: asp.net

I'm Saving a Image file in Solution explorer.

Here the Code that I'm using

```
String path = Server.MapPath("Img/");

FileUpload1.SaveAs(path+FileUpload1.FileName);
```

Comment: [Solution explorarrrrrr](http://johntomsett.files.wordpress.com/2014/03/14525_1_v12_tp.jpg)

Comment: do you mean in Application directory? what was the problem you have not explained yet? "Here is the Code" that is ok But, "what was the ISSUE?" Please let us know..?

Comment: The problem is Image not showing in Solution explorer

Answer (score 1):

Click `Show All Files`. They should be there . Right clik and `Include In Project`.